# Empty EditText value displayed in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am new in Android development and I got a problem. I have 2 `EditText` fields of login and password and 1 `Button`. When I click on the `Button`, I am getting `AlertDialog` with message "**Logged in as** " but I need it to be "**Logged in as *value entered into "login" `EditText`**".
The `EditText` value is always empty. It's just a simple implementation, but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText loginText;
    EditText passwText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null, false);

        loginText = (EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.loginText);
        passwText = (EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.passText);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view) {
                handleLoginDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleLoginDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null, false);

        String st = loginText.getText().toString();

        if (loginText != null && passwText != null){
            builder.setMessage("Logged in as " + st);
        }
        else
            builder.setMessage("Login or password was not entered!" );
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start the answer with **what you did**:

You inflated 2 same layouts as :

1. `View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null, false);`
2. `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);`

Let's call this second inflation as `view1` which is the original view that was inflated for the `Fragment` and also is the one that is **returned** in the `onViewCreated()` method.

Then, you set the set the `onClickListener` for `button_first` of `view1`.

Then, inside the `handleDialogLogin()` method, you try to get the text value of `EditText` fields that you created with `view2` object.
**That's where it went wrong**. Because, during app usage, you insert the text in `EditText` fields of `view1` but you are asking for text value of `EditText` fields of `view2` which will obviously be empty.

The correct and clean approach is here :

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText loginText;
    EditText passwText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // just inflate the layout for this fragment as it is not correct
        // place for declaring and initializing views
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    // this is the best place for declaring and initializing views
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // declare and initialize your EditText here 
        loginText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.loginText);
        passwText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passText);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view) {
                handleLoginDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleLoginDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());

        String st = loginText.getText().toString().trim();
        String pt = passText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (st.isEmpty() && pt.isEmpty())
           builder.setMessage("Login or password was not entered!" );
        else
           builder.setMessage("Logged in as " + st);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :) I thought, that inflate() method just gets view instance and you can do it any time to get some value. Seems like it's not. So if I re-inflate some view, all what I did already with it in program is lost?

Comment: I think they both exist and the view you inflated previously i.e `view2` is being overlaid by later inflated view i.e `view1`. So, you cannot enter anything into that view as it is not in focus but the later one is in focus. You can try checking whether the `EditText` object are `null` or not inside the `handleLoginDialog` method in your original code. My guess is that they are non-null but they will always remain empty and will get destroyed when the whole `Fragment` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, But this does not use onViewCreated

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
EditText loginText;
EditText passText;
Button btnLogin;
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null, false);

    loginText = (EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.loginText);
    passText = (EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.passText);
    btnLogin = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.button_first);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handleLoginDialog();
        }
    });

    return view2;
}

private void handleLoginDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null, false);

    String st = loginText.getText().toString().trim();
    String pt = passText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (st.isEmpty() && pt.isEmpty()){
        builder.setMessage("Login or password was not entered!" );
    }
    else
        builder.setMessage("Logged in as " + st);
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safe side would be to send the `loginText` as string parameter in `handleLoginDialog` method and check there if the string is empty.

Comment: It's empty, but I didn't know why. That's the thing.